# How to filter on array of array in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have below array of arrays in my React application which I need to filter based on first column.

First column contains list of companies.

```
const rowData = [
  ['Capri LLC', '0012345', 'A0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
  ['Capricorn INC', '0022345', 'B0012', 'N', 'View Details'],
  ['Cancer INC', '0033345', 'A0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
  ['Gemini LLC', '0052345', 'C0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
  ['Leo Land INC', '0052345', 'D0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
  ['Capri LLC', '0012345', 'A0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
  ['Capricorn INC', '0022345', 'B0012', 'N', 'View Details'],
  ['Cancer INC', '0033345', 'A0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
  ['Gemini LLC', '0052345', 'C0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
  ['Leo Land INC', '0052345', 'D0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
];
```

So if I search for Capri, it should the final output should be,

```
const rowData = [
      ['Capri LLC', '0012345', 'A0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
      ['Capricorn INC', '0022345', 'B0012', 'N', 'View Details'],
      ['Capri LLC', '0012345', 'A0012', 'Y', 'View Details'],
      ['Capricorn INC', '0022345', 'B0012', 'N', 'View Details'],
];
```

I tried applying the .filter() method we use for one dimensional array however while applying that for array of arrays, I am doing some syntax mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
rowData.filter(a => a[0].includes('Capri'));
```